# why is it important to recommend default values and lengths of mysql data on table creation?

Tags: php, mysql

If I do it using php instead, how does it benefit me making sure that I have defined them in the creation of the mysql table?

Comment: I can make sure that input on a form is under the string length of say 15 characters, why does it benefit me setting the max-length to 15 in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Basic: Well, it has to be set to *something*!

Comment: Not on my phpmyadmin! I am using mysql version 5.8.8 on wamp server, maybe I should re download it.

Comment: You are lost man. phpmyadmin is setting a default for you. But just because it does, it doesn't mean that **you don't have to**. I mean, c'mon. What on earth do you think the length of your fields get set to if you don't tell phpmyadmin? Imaginary numbers? Things that magically adapt in size to whatever your web form sends?

Comment: This isn't in anyway relevant to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Default values are useful**

So that if you do an `insert` you don't have to state each and every field explicitly.

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  type CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'F',
  invoicenumber VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  count INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1);
```

Now if I do an insert I need only do this

```
INSERT INTO test (invoicenumber) values ('20110125');

or this, the two are the same

INSERT INTO test VALUES (null,default,'20110125',default);
```

If I do a select I get

```
SELECT * FROM test;

+----+------+---------------+-------+
| id | type | invoicenumber | count | 
+----+------+---------------+-------+
|  1 | 'F'  | '20110125'    | 1     |
+----+------+---------------+-------+
```

The id is assigned an `auto_increment`ing id (starting at 1,2,3,4,...)
the type = 'F' `default`
the count = 1  `default`
Only the invoicenumber I must supply, I cannot forget, because I stated that it must be filled. `not null`

**Stating the length of fields is useful**
Because the shorter your fields are the faster your queries will run and the less network traffic and harddisk space you need. *(oversimplification, but good rule of thumb)*

Comment: +1 The answer is helpful but it's questionably true. Field lengths don't affect field comparisons. Network overhead and storage are a function of spacd acutally used, not max definitions. Defaults don't affect any of them.

Comment: Trying to join fields with different charsets has given me a lot of grief.

Comment: And I'm trying to keep it simple, so yes, technical details suffer a bit I agree.

Comment: Thanks. And note he was asking about default values and lengths, not field types which definitely belong in DDL and can't be defined in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the input, edited the answer to reflect your comments.

Answer (score 1):

> If I do it using php instead, how does
>   it benefit me making sure that I have
>   defined them in the creation of the
>   mysql table?

You define your table structures independently of what you use at your application.

> I can make sure that input on a form
>   is under the string length of say 15
>   characters, why does it benefit me
>   setting the max-length to 15 in
>   phpmyadmin.

1. You don't define a max-length in phpmyadmin. You define that in DDL *via* phpmyadmin. This is an important distinction to make *if you really want to understand what the heck you are doing*.
2. What prevents you (or someone working on your code) from entering a bug, changing the string length restriction in your form (or completely removing it by accident)? What happens then?

Anyways, you still have to define the size of your database table fields no matter what. Your database is your model, your data model, not your web forms. Your web forms work off it.

Taking the database defaults is just laziness and horrible design, (not to mention inefficient.) Say you are using an admin tool like phpmyadmin and that thing by defaults sets your database fields to, say, length 255. And yet your actual data fields will be no larger than 15, are you willing to waste all that just because your form defines a limit?

Your form defines a limit on what the user can enter (and send to the back end). But that will get stored in database fields that are much larger than that if you don't define their sizes as well. Food for thought.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't. Keep it simple; set defaults one place or the other. And only if there's a logically legitimate default value. Don't make up something just to have one.

The application needs to drive the tool, not vice versa.

Lots of application control battles between database admins and application developers get fought this way. Try to get this one cleared up early to avoid both code and people conflicts.

It's worth spending some time thinking about and it's easy to reflexively install some funny stuff. One app I'm workng on has most of the string fields set to NOT NULL with a default of "" (empty string), and then adds a lot of code to detect and flag errors on empty strings.

Comment: Limits on the front end are just for limiting input. Limits on the back end are for storage. They are not the same, ergo, you need both.

Comment: PHP is not just for input. It's also for business rules and classes. And your rules can be/usually are more granular than what can be accomplished in database defaults. Putting similar rules both places increases coupling/decreases cohesion.

And a lot more people are comfortable with PHP than with DDL.

Comment: Are you `accusing` me of something X;-|

Comment: Don't get touchy - I upvoted your post. It would be helpful to discuss the merits rather than point out how you feel, though.

Comment: I was trying to be funny/sarcastic, SO hard to get that right in writing, alas... I didn't have any feelings. Am a bit curious *who* my friend is, because I missed that part.

Comment: I just thought it was interesting that a good quesion with a lot of potential discussion opportunity got an answer accepted 11 minutes after it was asked - maybe he trusts not to think further based on previous answers you've given.

Comment: @le dorfier - I know that PHP is not just for input and that is also for business rules and classes (just like any other front end or back-end programming language/system). It still does not explain why someone would not explicitly define field sizes at the db level. Do you leave them at their defaults (usually much larger than what your UI input fields will be)? **Do you think that's a good idea?**. Also, DDL is **a lot** simpler than PHP (plus you have phpmyadmin). It's about knowing how to build systems properly. If pple can't understand DDL, they shouldn't be programming. Period.

Comment: The question was "how does it benefit me." I think the answer if you're defining it at the PHP level is "not very much if at all." Of course you define field lengths - I didn't say otherwise.

Comment: So if you agree that we need to define field lengths (which are themselves storage limits), then you are in agreement with my first comment, that we define limits on both on the front-end and on the back-end. Correct?

Comment: I don't think you read the question the same way I did. I was  discussing the benefits of the procedures we of course follow. You were commenting on whether to follow standard procedures, and I agree with you entirely. And since you didn't find much benefit from either lengths or defaults, I would imagine we would agree.